# error: expected ')' before 'n'

Tags: c

I am getting this compilation error . I tried a few troubleshooting steps like rename the def.h file to defdif.h to prevent the system files to be included. But this error doesnt go .Any one has a idea.

```
core/def.c: error: expected ')' before 'n'
core/def.c: error: expected ')' before 'n
```

def.c file

```
u16_t
lwip_htons(u16_t n)
  {
   return( ((n & 0xff) << 8) | ((n & 0xff00) >> 8) );
  }


u32_t
lwip_htonl(u32_t n)
{
return ((n & 0xff) << 24) |
   ((n & 0xff00) << 8) |
   ((n & 0xff0000UL) >> 8) |
   ((n & 0xff000000UL) >> 24);
}
```

Comment: What are u16_t and u32_t? Are their definitions visible at that point?

Comment: @ŝraddhaj: what is the line making the error?

Comment: Which line does the error message correspond to?  Where are `u16_t` and `u32_t` defined?

Comment: Afaict without knowing the compiler, almost definitely an error in (or absence of) the definition of u16_t or u32_t.

Comment: IIRC that code is part of the TCP/IP stack and compiles fine... except when something is messed up with the headers - esp. the declaration/definition of `u16_t` and `u32_t` and the relationship of the underlying types is important...

Comment: Could you post your `def.h` and `Makefile`

Comment: @sraddhaj: please post the code with line numbers.

Comment: Renaming the .h file will stop the header being included but will not stop the .c file (where you are seeing the error) from being built. To stop the .c file being built you would need to change your makefile or project settings (depending on your build system). But as others have said, you probably have an issue with another header not being included that is in fact needed...

Answer (score 3):

An error like:

```
u16_t lwip_htons (u16_t n)
core/def.c: error: expected ')' before 'n'
```

is almost *always* related to he fact that the `u16_t` type is not defined at the point where you use it.

For example, in `gcc`:

```
int fn (u16_t n) { return n; }
int main (void) { return 0; }
```

gives you:

```
qq.c:1: error: expected ')' before 'n'
```

the exact error message you describe. That error disappears when I change it to:

```
typedef int u16_t;
int fn (u16_t n) { return n; }
int main (void) { return 0; }
```

It's therefore *reasonably* safe to assume that the type is not defined (you can test this by temporarily defining it yourself immediately before `lwip_htons` like I have done).

Now I'm not sure what hideous deformation you've inflicted on your code base but, if it's the package I'm thinking of, the definition for these in in `arch/cc.h`. Make sure that's included in the chain somewhere.

If it's not the one I think it is, you'll have to go searching for the `typedef` yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Answers all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted the *standardized* `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` here instead, and they are available through `#include <stdint.h>`.